# Short story involving attack on clan gathering of the Jones by aliens ending with the triumphant singing of the clan song

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read in the 1960's but may be older than that. Clan gathering is defended successfully from alien attack hence the triumphant singing.
Definitely science fiction as 1) alternate world where clans are still prevalent in a modern setting 2) The attack is by aliens and is defeated by some sort of international rescue organisation (well before Thunderbirds were ever thought of!)

Comment: This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the [scope defined in the help center](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there anything fantastic (or science fictional) about this story?  If not, I believe you might be able to ask about it on [literature.se], but more details would help there too.

Comment: Definitely science fiction as 1) alternate world where clans are still prevalent in a modern setting 2) The attack is by aliens and is defeated by some sort of international rescue organisation (well before Thunderbirds were ever thought of!)

Comment: Could you add those details to the question?

Comment: [Kronos by Allen Steele](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43279) is all about clans in space. Much too late to be what you're thinking of, but something you might enjoy.

Comment: Given that the original Thunderbirds show started production in 1964 and that Fireball XL5 was even earlier, if you read the story in the 60's the concept of an International Rescue style organization was already around